# SVG <use> element doesn't work on iOS or Safari in dynamic environment

Tags: ios, reactjs, svg, safari, href

I can't get svg `<use>` elements to work on iOS in any browser. It also doesn't work on Safari on Mac. It does work on Android and in every other browser that I've tested on PC or Mac. In other words, it is probably a webkit problem. The environment is React when a `<path>` className is updated dynamically based upon system/user inputs and changes. This `<path>` element is hidden using viewBox and is referenced by a `<use>` element in a large svg element. This is the HTML produced by the React jsx:

```
<form
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0">
   ...
      <path id="path9146scheduleamap" name="path9146scheduleamap" d="m 146.86174,202.08294 v -13.04313 h 19.67563 v 13.04313 z m 0,0" class="alert00During"></path>
   ...
   </svg>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
            <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mapSVG" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 199.58284 125.05578" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="100%" class="mapSVGClass" style="cursor: move; user-select: none; touch-action: none; transform-origin: 50% 50%; transition: none 0s ease 0s; transform: scale(0.67032) translate(-107.635px, -394.821px);">
               ...
               <use id="use_path9146scheduleamap" href="#path9146scheduleamap" xlink:href="#path9146scheduleamap" d="m 146.86174,202.08294 v -13.04313 h 19.67563 v 13.04313 z m 0,0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-8.574823231476401,-100.56069682128418)"></use>
               ...
            </svg>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is the React code that updates the svg path elements.

```
class Venues extends Component{
   ...
   map2Venues(venue){
      return (
         <path
           id={venue.mapIdentifier} 
           name={venue.mapIdentifier} 
           key={venue.mapIdentifier}
           d={venue.pathD}
           className={venue.alertClass}
         />
      );
   }
   ...
   render() {
      ...
      return (
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0" >
            {this.reducedVenues.map((venue) => this.map2Venues(venue))}
         </svg>
      );
      ...
   }
}
```

Here is the React for the svg element with the `<use>` element:

```
class Map extends Component {
   ...
   render() {
      ...
      return (
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <div
                id="svgMapDiv"
                ref={this.svgDivRef}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.svgMap }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      );
      ...
   }
}
```

The svg with the `<use>` element is only loaded once on component creation while the class attribute in the svg with `<path>` elements are updated frequently. I understand the danger associated with the inline svg. It is controlled. If it is a bug with webkit, a workaround solution for React would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I confirmed in Safari on MacOS that when the `<path>` elements and corresponding attributes are statically applied and exist before the referencing `<use>` elements are created, the attributes are propagated to the `<use>` elements properly. More proof the problem is the `<use>` elements aren't updating when the `<path>` elements are updated dynamically.

I found this [bug description](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111927) which doesn't seem to be resolved. I tried the work around described by Stuart P. Bentley on 2013-03-09 14:34:36 in that bug description, but it still does not work. That is, when attributes are changed directly and not by class or style attributes (a real pain), it still does not work on all iOS browsers and Safari on MacOS (but does work on all the other browsers and os). For example, changing the React code for the Venues component above still does not work:

```
class Venues extends Component{
   ...
   map2Venues(venue){
    let fill = "";
    let stroke = "";
    let stroke_width = "";
    let animation_name = "";
    let animation_duration = "";
    let animation_iteration_count = "";
    if(venue.alertClass.includes("alertSelected")){
      fill = "purple";
      stroke = "purple";
      stroke_width = "1";
    }else if(venue.alertClass.includes("alert00During")){
      fill = "green";
      stroke = "green";
      stroke_width = "1";
    }
    ...
    return (
      <path
        id={venue.mapIdentifier} 
        name={venue.mapIdentifier} 
        key={venue.mapIdentifier}
        d={venue.pathD}
        opacity="0.8"
        fill={fill}
        stroke={stroke}
        stroke-width={stroke_width}
      />
    );
  }
  ...
  render() {
     ...
     return (
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0" >
           {this.reducedVenues.map((venue) => this.map2Venues(venue))}
        </svg>
      );
      ...
  }
}
```

Therefore, I still need a workaround to this bug because it doesn't seem to be being addressed. (Isn't this an important capability to have especially since all the other browsers and platforms support it?)

Comment: For troubleshooting: test the static html/svg output (without any dynamic icon swapping) in iOS/macOS. If the `<use>` elements still don't show up it might be related to safaris/webkits issues with transform-origin and other transformation related properties.

Comment: Yes. Confirmed to work when static. See my update. Do you have a link that describes the safari/webkit transformation issue. Maybe I can figure out a way to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on your issue! If it works with static svg - transformations are apparently not the main problem. (However, seaching for previous questions on SO about `transform-origin` && `safari`  ||  `transform-box` might be the best source for this topic (the name is safari – no wonder things get wild sometimes ;) )  
If you're dynamically updating `<path>` elements, why not updating e.g.  `d` attributes directly? Updating/replacing svg asset instances as self contained inlined (instead of referenced `<use>`)  elements might be also an appropriate approach.

Comment: I have to research that. However, I think updating the path elements directly instead of using the use statements will require converting the entire SVG map to react elements or going against react state principals with straight javascript. However, if that is the only way, then I'll have to look into it.

Comment: You might also use external svg as [described here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/) if you don't need to update map elements completely (like changing their path geometry). So a use instance might look something like this `<svg><use href="mappasset1.svg#venue012"></svg>`

Comment: I've had to move on to work other functions. Give me some time to attempt these ideas. I think both will require directly modifying the '<use>' elements to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** As far as I can determine, iOS, Safari and the webkit mobile browsers still do not support any dynamic updating of `<use>` elements in SVG images using typical React component updates as described in the question. It also does not support directly modifing the SVG element after it has been added to the React DOM (i.e., after using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` call). However, it is possible to directly modify the SVG ***before*** `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is called by using javascript (or jQuery) to modify the SVG text.

General Steps:

1. Create a `<defs>` element,
2. Create and add the newly styled `<path>`'s to this `<defs>` element (the `<path>`'s the `<use>` elements are referencing),
3. Grab the SVG text `let newSvgMap = this.state.svgMap`;
4. Add the `<defs>` element to `newSvgMap` with javascript or jQuery,
5. Update the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which updates the component with the new `<path>` styles by updating the state using the `this.setState({ svgMap: newSvgMap })` call, then
6. Repeat this process with any changes to the styles by creating a new `<def>` and replacing the previous one in the `this.state.svgMap` text.

Example:

```
let defsElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','defs'); 
venues.forEach(venue=>{
    let pathElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
    pathElement.setAttribute('id', venue.mapIdentifier);
    pathElement.setAttribute('name', venue.mapIdentifier);
    pathElement.setAttribute('key', venue.mapIdentifier);
    pathElement.setAttribute('d', venue.pathD);
    pathElement.setAttribute('opacity', venue.opacity);
    pathElement.setAttribute('fill', venue.fill);
    pathElement.setAttribute('stroke', venue.stroke);
    pathElement.setAttribute('stroke-width', venue.stroke-width);
    defsElement.appendChild(pathElement);
})
defsElement.setAttribute('id', 'scheduleamap-defs');
let defElementstring = defsElement.outerHTML;
let currentSvgDefString = this.state.svgMap.match(/<defs id="myUniqueId-defs">.*<\/defs>/);
if (currentSvgDefString !== null) {
    let newSvgMap = this.state.svgMap.replace(currentSvgDefString[0], defElementstring);
    this.setState({ svgMap: newSvgMap });//This updates the dangerouslySetInnerHTML in the component which updates all the styles
}
```

Note:

1. I'd set the `<path>`'s attributes directly instead of using classes.
2. I would initialize the SVG file with an empty `<defs id="myUniqueId-defs"><\/defs>` already added to make the javascript in react simpler (otherwise you have to also accommodate adding the initial `<defs>` instead of a simple replace.
3. I've tested that this works for animations. I'd assume it works for any functionality supported in normal static SVG elements.

This isn't the most efficient solution, but as far as I can tell, it is the only solution to get dynamic updates to styles in SVG elements in the iOS, Safari, and webkit mobile browsers.